# In IntelliJ IDEA, is there a way to see background task output?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Say I'm importing new project and it's taking way too long in my opinion. Background task is stuck for example at "Gradle: build".

How can I debug (verify), if it's doing anything? Is there a way to see any specific output?

Comment: You can see the progress bar for background tasks. That's the only thing out there. :))

Comment: It means that tons of possibly useful data is being ignored... I'd love a button attaching me to the full output. :)

Comment: In addition, at the end/crash of any task you can see the final stack trace. There's no way to perform any kind of 'debug' operation. :))

Comment: I've created issue for that.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168228

Comment: On unix like os, try to launch idea from the bash.

Answer (score 3):

There is already an open feature request for that, please feel free to vote:

- [IDEA-157505](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157505) View Gradle output when importing project

Comment: This issue is closed and has been added they claim, it says to see the output from Gradle project refresh in shown in View | Tool Windows | Build tool window. That said that Window is not showing for me in Community edition 2018.2

Comment: Try 2019 release.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the log file of IntelliJ IDEA. For macOS run:

```
tail -f ~/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.3/idea.log
```

with the correct path corresponding to your IntelliJ version. For Linux and Windows, same principle, see [Advanced configuration - Logs directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory)